# How to select contact form dynamic values using query string

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a contact form in wordpress site.

I have created a drop down field, It has 2 options `dynamic` and `custom` and my url `/contact/?option=custom` has this option value.

I am using below hook to add select options :

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'dynamic_field_values_locations', 10, 2);
function dynamic_field_values_location( $tag, $unused )
{
    $tag['raw_values'][] = 'dynamic';
    $tag['values'][] = 'dynamic';
    $tag['labels'][] = 'dynamic';

    $tag['raw_values'][] = 'custom';
    $tag['values'][] = 'custom';
    $tag['labels'][] = 'custom';

    return $tag;
}
```

I want that this drop down field selected as `custom` option which is in query string.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

When creating your shortcode you must set the default attribute like so:

```
[select* default:get
```

Also, keep in mind that the contact 7 form function handles the default setting needs the query string parameter to be the name of the select control you have used. So in your case, you would need to set this `/contact/?your-select-name=custom` in order for the custom value to be selected as default.